# jsf application performance improvement tips

Tags: performance, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets, myfaces

How to improve performance of jsf myfaces based application  ?

Some tips that I have collected so far

### Trinidad

- Set following init parameters to false in web.xml

  - org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.DEBUG_JAVASCRIPT
  - org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.DISABLE_CONTENT_COMPRESSION
  - org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION
- use client-side state saving
- clear pageflow context map when not in use

### Myfaces

- Set following init parameters to false in web.xml

  - org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION
  - org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION
  - org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML
  - org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE
- Reduce value of org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION from init param (default is 20)

### facelets

- Set following init parameters to false in web.xml

  - facelets.DEVELOPMENT
  - facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS
- set facelets.BUFFER_SIZE and com.sun.faces.responseBufferSize to large value like 10000000
- set facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD to -1

Is there anything else to add to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across the following link. Will be useful if you're using ADF based (now MyFaces Trinidad) implementation.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28967/web_getstarted006.htm

Answer (score 2):

Moving to *Stateless* JSF would offer a great performance boost.  Now it's possible to use JSF entirely stateless. See [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140626062226/http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/) & [this issue](https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/1055). A payoff is that you can't create views dynamically (e.g. by binding, JSTL tags, etc), nor manipulate it after creation.

---

> A Stateless JSF operation mode
>   would be incredibly useful for high-load applications and
>   architectures:
>
> https://web.archive.org/web/20140626062226/http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/#comment-4
>
> This has previously been suggested by Jacob:
>   http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jhook/archive/2006/01/experiment_goin.html
>
> This would help JSF ditch the stigma of "slow and memory hog," and
>   help keep up with current tech trends (stateless architectures.)